# NetBeans IDE maven project unable to solve dependencies

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dependencies

After using eclipse for ages I am porting myself to NetBeans IDE. I am opening my existing maven project and all seems ok, but when I am trying to build the project it is throwing error saying "Could not resolve dependencies for project" though the JAR files are present in my .m2 directory.

I am using a ubuntu 12.10 and netbeans version 7.3.1

Any suggestions on the same are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a jar that is available through a central repository? If not you could try to re-install it manually: in your project > dependencies, find your jar, right click > manually install artifact > select the jar.

Comment: Yes that jar is available through a central repo, and it gets downloaded when i build through command prompt, alongside the build runs successfully from terminal.

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried a simple "Clean & Build"? Otherwise you can define a custom goal: right click on project > Custom... > Goals then type your goal, for example: `clean install -DskipTests -e -X` and run it.

Comment: Another possibility is if the repo is not setup properly in your pom - Netbeans only look at Maven Central I think.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Any suggestions on the same are highly appreciated."*

This may not solve your current problem, but is a suggestion for the future, or even if you want to do it for your current projects.

[image]

First thing is you need to make sure your project was imported correctly as a maven project. As you can see in the image, all maven projects, have a little `m` in the top left of the project logo. The first project is a maven web app, the second a regular maven app, and the last a regular java app. If you see your projects as maven apps, then all you need to do is right-click on the `Dependencies` and select **add dependeny**. You can search your local repo from the dialog that opens. The once you select will get automatically inserted into you pom, and you will see teh jar in the `Dependencies` folder.

If you don't see the depencies folder, then your projects were not imported as maven projects.

Answer (score 1):

I had different situation. 
My .m2 folder was a bit large, so I decided to delete it. 
When I opened one Vaadin project I was working on which consists of regular modules, almost all dependencies was resolved. I'm saying **almost** because, one module which is dependent on the other independent maven library project could not resolve three dependencies at all! 
After a while, I opened that independent library module and rebuilt it. As soon as I started, I noticed missing dependencies started to download and the problem was resolved immediately ! 
Hope this experience will help.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking on Dependencies under the Project tab allows to install .jar  dependencies to a local repository e.g. on linux .jar will be installed to

```
/home/username/.m2/repository
```

where .m2 is a hidden maven folder. You can view folder contents by command

```
cd /home/username/.m2/repository
ls -a
```