# Why is Netbeans not recognising maven dependency imports in my Grails app?

Tags: java, maven, grails, netbeans, dependencies

I've added a maven repo to my Grails BuildConfig and a couple of compile dependencies. Unfortunately, Netbeans isn't recognising the import statements. It all compiles and works fine, just intellisense and the red underlines are spoiling my fun.

[image: The ugliness :(]

Comment: see if this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405878/netbeans-ide-maven-project-unable-to-solve-dependencies

Comment: has anyone solved this ?

Comment: @angryip I don't remember what the solution was, but it was something to do with Netbeans not using the correct BuildPath.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, the dependency management of Grails has somewhat changed some time ago - they moved from Ivy to Maven as default, some Grails repositories seem to have been moved / shut down, etc. (see http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/migrateToTheNewCentralRepository.html)

It seems that NetBeans isn't aware of these changes, and thus doesn't support using Maven in Grails.

You can still manually add the desired libary by copying the .jar file in the lib directory of your Grails application (you might have to run "clean" in NetBeans). That worked for me.